# List<Dictionary<string,string>> bounding to telerik reporting

Tags: silverlight, list, dictionary, telerik-reporting

my code is:

```
IList<Dictionary<string,string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
        Dictionary<string, string> a = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        a["a1"] = "zhuwei";
        a["a2"] = "zhanglong";
        a["a3"] = "zhaoguang";

        Dictionary<string, string> b = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        b["a1"] = "zhuwei1";
        b["a2"] = "zhanglong1";
        b["a3"] = "zhaoguang1";

        list.Add(a);
        list.Add(b);

        this.DataSource = a;
```

the environment is silverlight
i want to show is:

---

```
   a1       a2           a3

zhuwei          zhanglong       zhaoguang

zhuwei1        zhanglong       zhaoguang
```

so,how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the report using the [ObjectDataSource Component](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/objectdatasource.html) that Telerik Reporting provides. You would have to assign your list to the DataSource property of the ObjectDataSource instance and then set the Report's DataSource to an InstanceReportSource that uses the ObjectDataSource e.g.:

// Creating a new report
    Telerik.Reporting.Report report = new Telerik.Reporting.Report();

```
// Assigning the ObjectDataSource component to the DataSource property of the report.
report.DataSource = objectDataSource;

// Use the InstanceReportSource to pass the report to the viewer for displaying
Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
reportSource.ReportDocument = report;

// Assigning the report to the report viewer.
reportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
```